# Unable to achieve this view in constraintLayout without adjusting dp in margin

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

So, the problem is that I am unable to make the Team A and Team B centrally aligned like that even after assigning a weight of 1 each to the text views. I am using constraint layout and not Linear or Relative. Also, I don't want to make those alignments for Team A and B by setting margins or like that. So if there is an appropriate attribute then please tell.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pooja.courtcounter.MainActivity">

    <TextView

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/team_nameA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/team_nameB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team B"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/team_nameA" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_nameA"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/points_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+3 points"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points3"  />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/points_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+2 points"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_3"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points2" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/free_throw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="free throw"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_2"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="freethrow" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your current code in you xml.

Comment: I have posted the code. All I want to know is that how to align the textviews (TeamA and TeamB ) centrally in the same line without adjusting margin dp, because by adjusting through dps , it won't help when I view the app in a table instead of a phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chain the child view in the constraint  layout. I have implemented it in team name and score. You can do same for the rest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/team_nameA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Team A"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/team_nameB"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/team_nameB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Team B"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/team_nameA"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_nameA"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/team_b_score"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/team_a_score"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_nameB"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If other problem arise, feel free to ask